# Filtering contents of an array that are a typeof string

Tags: javascript

I've successfully mapped the returned data to an array (`selected.data().map(d=>d)`) and can console log its contents to the console. However, the data includes both integers and strings. With this, I'd like to be able to log only the strings to the console. My approach below creates a new variable and filters through `theSelection` and returns data that is a `typeof` string. But nothing is being printed to the console (and no errors are being returned). If someone out there is able to look over my code and tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be helpful.

```
selected = lasso.selectedItems()
    .classed("selected", true)
    .attr("r", 18);

console.log(selected);

var theSelection = selected.data().map(d=>d);

console.log(theSelection);

var result = theSelection.filter(d => typeof d === 'String');

console.log(result);

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Data

```
var data = [
  ["Acid", 0.741593940836, 0.45657115, "Bristol", "Cardiff", "Birmingham"],
  ["Cannabis", 0.94183423, 0.31475, "Chester", "Swansea", "Brighton"],
  ["LSD", 0.1367547, 0.936115, "Newcastle", "Cardiff", "Bristol"],
];
```

[Google Chrome Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wF5Y.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your map line:

```
var theSelection = selected.data().map(d=>d);
```

..does nothing. It is basically saying, "map every element in the array to itself and return that array" (which is the same as the original array because no transformation has happened).

Because of this, your array `theSelected` is actually still a matrix (an array of arrays). Therefore, your filter statement is iterating through an array of only one item (another array with six items in it), and failing the `typeof` check because it is an array not a `String`.

You would need to utilize some other transform to flatten your "matrix" into one array like so:

```
const theSelection = [];
selected.data().forEach((arr) => {
    arr.forEach((d) => { theSelection.push(d); });
});
```

Comment: Ohh, so `(d=>d)` returns the original array and in turn, the `typeof` check is checking the array and not its contents? Therefore, using `forEach` on each array within the original 2d array pushes each individual element of the array to `theSelection` variable which inherently allows the `typeof` check to work? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, pushing every element of the individual arrays to `theSelection` gives you a flat array with all of the values from your 2D array. That way, when you iterate over it (using `filter`) it will be checking individual elements and not whole arrays.

Comment: There are also other ways to flatten out the 2D array that may be a little less straightforward, but provide fewer lines of code

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `typeof d === 'string'` as `d === typeof "string"` is incorrect because `d` refers to the value and you should check the type of `d` to be of `string` type.

```js
var theSelection = ['Acid', 'str', 0.123545, 'Bristol'];
var result = theSelection.filter(d => typeof d === 'string');
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's printing nothing, my friend. I've put a series of `console.log` statements before this code to see what if `theSelection` does indeed contain anything, and they do. But after the `result`, it holds nothing.

Comment: Console log `theSelection` and provide that

Comment: Just inserted a screenshot of the image

Comment: What is the value of `theSelection` @user172127

Comment: I just need that

Comment: Have a look at the screenshot, it's there (it's the second (middle) output)

Comment: @user172127 check the updated answer that is still working